# oracle/node multiple sql queried and combine into one object for result set

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am creating a REST api in nodejs using an oracle db. Currently I have four separate requests that results in 4 separate objects:

```
systemInfo: {}
systemContacts: {}
politicalInfo: {}
systemAdmin: {}
```

Each returns a single object. In reality, the bottom 3 list items are related to systemInfo, so ideally I would like to return a single object so that browser is only making a single api request. So the returned result set would look something like

```
systemInfo :{
     systemContact :{},
     systemAdmin: {},
     politicalInfo: {}
}
```

I'm not seeing a way to do this in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you currently fetching the individual objects? If each one is based on its own SQL query, then you're probably incurring one round trip for each one. If you can use a join to get the related parts down to a single query, that would take you down to two round trips.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am making individual queries. I'll look into making additional joins and see if that works.

Comment: This article may help. https://jsao.io/2015/07/relational-to-json-with-node-js/ The first solution demonstrates individual queries. The second one uses joins (don't go any further than that in the post). Also, ignore the use of the async module, like `async.parallel`. It's much easier to use async/await these days and I don't recommend using multiple connections for a single operation.

Comment: If you'd like to meet online so that I can see the app and offer suggestions, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/). If you do reach out, please include the URL to this Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks @DanMcGhan! Sorry for taking so long to respond. I had other obligations last week. I reworked the main query to include all the part except for one, and sing the article you sent is helpful to embed that into the results.

Comment: Excellent. So all good now?